# How to place portlet in the header?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I use Liferay Portal 6.0 CE and I need to place portlet (two buttons) in the header of the standart template, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

How can I do it?..

I need to get access to the layer that is beyond the scope of my template:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following documentation and I think that I got the solution:

[Liferay Themes: Customizing Liferay’s Look & Feel](http://content.liferay.com/document/Liferay%20Themes.pdf)

Comment: Yes, Themes are the way to go with this!

Comment: If you have any questions, post it and link it here! :)